# How do I sort Game by Match DateTime starting from now till infinity in my app

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

I have been building this app for quite a while now and i am facing just a little sorting problem
I have a `game` Table and it has these

```
  t.integer :team_1
  t.text :team_1_news
  t.integer :team_2
  t.text :team_2_news
  t.text :match_details
  t.string :featured_photo
  t.string :game_prediciton
  t.text :reason_for_bet_tip
  t.text :head_to_head
  t.string :stat
  t.datetime :time
```

I want to sort my the records by the `:time` and in such a way that it checks the DateTime.now and returns records of Games that's Upcoming/ coming next i.e., it ignores all past `matches/game` and renders the rest that is yet to occur. Thanks

a scope for the `game` model is all i need, Thanks Guys

Answer (score 0):

I will assume that your model is called Game.

In that case I would probably do a query that looks something like

```
@future_game = Game.where("created_at >= ?", Time.zone.now.beginning_of_day)
```

You then have a @future_game variable that you can use in your views to display. 
You can also chain it if you need a special order like

```
Post.where("created_at >= ?", Time.zone.now.beginning_of_day).order(:time :desc)
```

or if you need ascending, just reverse the order

```
Post.where("created_at >= ?", Time.zone.now.beginning_of_day).order(:time :asc)
```